# missing $ inserted in figure caption

Tags: equations

using a formula in my figure I got this error , here is my formula, how do I correct it ? thanks  a lot

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Net = \sum w_{i} p_{i}}
\label{fig:f7}
\includegraphics[width=9cm, height=5cm]{3-7}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: all these questions are very similar, you may be best to step back and start with a latex tutorial. you need math mode `$\mathrm{Net}=\sum w_{i} p_{i}$`

Comment: also don't use `[H]` unless you are sure you need it and don't specify both `width` and `height` as it will distort the image.

Comment: You find a good tutorial at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/ and also, in Italian, http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/ArteLaTeX.pdf

Comment: if I don't use H, and h instead , the photos run here and there and don't place where I want

Comment: H is the best one

Comment: @Farzad64 See Section 6.2 of the second guide I mentioned above.

Comment: No If you are using H then you should not be using `figure` at all. The _whole point_ of `figure` is to specify that the figures may be moved.

Comment: really ? so how do I write it ?

Comment: @Farzad64 The whole reason for the figure environment is to allow the figure to be moved by LaTeX to the place where it is best fitting without interrupting the textflow. Forcing it (more or less) at a certain position using the `[H]` parameters completely defeats that purpose. And given all your other questions I heavily agree with David Carlisle: Don't you think you should do yourself (and everyone else for that matter) the favour of learning the basics of LaTeX before writing a whole thesis with it!?

Comment: Thank you dear Manuel , the thing is now I have almost finished my thesis, If I had to read all the latex first, I had to read more than 500 pages, that was so much more than the pages of my thesis, I just started with a ready theme, wrote the formulas, hopfully in most parts there were no errors,ran generally, now I just see some errors here and there

Comment: You do not need to read anything like 500 pages to learn the basics. In fact, I have no idea where you get that figure from. You will *save time* if you stop and learn the basics. Thinking not doing so will save you time is just a mistake.

Comment: @Farzad64 I am sorry, but this is conceptually nonsense. 1. Nobody asked you to read a 500 pages compendium, there are great beginners books with 60-120 pages that guide you through the whole process of setting up a document and explaining to you how it works. 2. You should have invested that time, instead of writing everything together in a format you do not understand and now being confronted with tons of errors which you have no clue how they even come into existence or explain in a forum. And don't tell me they just now popped up, they must have been there all the time!

Comment: you are totally right , I know but I had no time , in a rush I did, still very thankful to this website

Comment: *give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime* Reading an introduction, you will be able to help yourselv and will never be hungry for solutions again.

Comment: *You will waste more time this way.* This is *not* an efficient use of your time, never mind ours. Taking the time to learn the basics will cost you less time, effort and frustration than trying to solve problems you do not understand the first thing about. Using a 'theme' from wherever which you do not understand and cannot assess the quality of is a recipe for just your experience: errors, frustration and confusion. It is also a huge time-sink.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need math mode

```
$\mathrm{Net}=\sum w_{i} p_{i}$
```

Comment: I almost feel ashamed that i upvoted this kind of question/answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B You shouldn't feel ashamed, you should do it more often!